# In Excel, how do I find the margin of error and confidence intervals for surveys with different sample sizes and population sizes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, survey, confidence-interval, sample-size

I'm calculating the NPS (Net Promoter Scores) for about 50 different sessions at a recent event. Each session was attended by about 50-500 people, and the number of survey responses for each session ranges between 15-400.

**If I know:**

- **The number of respondents for each session (sample size)**
- **The number of attendees for each session (population size)**
- **The NPS score for each session (average rating**, basically—more info below)

**How can I figure out the margin of error and/or confidence intervals for each session in Excel?**

What formula would I use where, for example, X = sample size, Y = population size, and Z = avg rating?

I don't need this to be incredibly correct as long as I'm in the ballpark—so you can ignore the NPS part which might throw things off slightly:

- This is slightly complicated by the fact that NPS is a weird metric.
  It asks "How likely would you be to recommend X to a friend or
  colleague?" with a scale from 0-10 (10 = extremely likely, 0 = not at
  all likely). You then count every 10 and 9 as a "promoter," count
  every 8 and 7 as a "neutral" or "passive," and count everything
  between 6 and 0 as a "detractor."
- You then get the NPS by subtracting the detractors from the promoters, dividing that number by the total responses, then multiplying it by 100, so: ((Promoters - Detractors)/(Total responses))*100. NPS sort of flattens every  response to a +1, 0, or -1, so it might complicate the calculations.

Assume I've already calculated the NPS for each session. I'm trying to figure out the margin of errors and/or confidence intervals for each session using Excel.

So, for example, my data would look like this:

[image]

Again,  you can ignore the NPS stuff if it makes it easier and just assume it's an average rating where people were asked to rate each session from -100 to +100. **What function(s) would I use in Excel to find the margin of error and/or confidence intervals for each session, given the sample size and target population size, and the average rating?**

Comment: There is two inbuilt functions for Confidence interval in Excel: `=CONFIDENCE.NORM()` and `=CONFIDENCE.T()`, depending on which probability distribution you use. "[CONFIDENCE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/confidence-function-75ccc007-f77c-4343-bc14-673642091ad6)"

Comment: @Wizhi Thanks, but those functions take sample size, confidence level, and standard deviation as inputs. I don't want to use standard deviation, I want to use target population size (i.e., the total number of people that the sample represents) to figure out the margin of error or confidence level.